# How to prevent the q will be uppercase automatically while try to quit vim?

Tags: vim

Did you guys notice that in command mode of vim, some times when we tried to type "q" and press enter to exit vim but it would automactially turn the "q" into uppercase? How to prevent it?

Comment: Turn off your capslock, or let go of shift faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your `.vimrc`:

```
command! -bang Q q<bang>
```

This makes `:Q` imitate `:q`, and `:Q!` act as `:q!`.